# laravel api Email verification link gives unauthenticated error

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-passport

The Verification link send in email gives unauthenticated how to fix this ?
while in web routes is working fine but in api method it gives error ?

verificationController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Email Verification Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling email verification for any
    | user that recently registered with the application. Emails may also
    | be re-sent if the user didn't receive the original email message.
    |
    */
    use VerifiesEmails;
    protected $redirectTo = '/login';

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return response()->json('Email Verified');
        }
        else {
            return response()->json('Email not verified');
        }
    }
    /**
     * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
   public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        auth()->loginUsingId($request->route('id'));
        if ($request->route('id') != $request->user()->getKey()) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
         return redirect($this->redirectPath());

        }
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return response(['message'=>'Already verified']);
            // return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }
        if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
        }
        return response(['message'=>'Successfully verified']);
    }

    /**
     * Resend the email verification notification.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function resend(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return response()->json('User already have verified email!', 422);
//            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }
        $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
        return response()->json('The notification has been resubmitted');
       return back()->with('resent', true);
    }
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
}
```

and in my user class

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
        use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
```

And this is my routes

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {


 //email verification//
  Route::get('email/resend', 'Api\Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Api\Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::post('email/verify', 'Api\Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
//email//
```

i have tried all method but still it gives error and my app env. url is http://localhost
and i tried to use it with notification and add frontend.php but still gives me the same error how to fix it ?
if any one knows pls let me know ????

Comment: Are you using a custom verification, or the default Laravel email authentication? Also: what is the exact error, because if you're using the API, it could be something with user tokens, since the API expects a user token to be present.

Comment: the redirect link on click gives {"error":"unauthenticated.","code":401}

Comment: no simple using the 5.7 function and just copied the web route controller and changed the functions

Comment: If you're using the default Laravel email verification, you should use the steps described in this guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification. This way, you're sure you haven't missed a file. If you just copy-paste some files, you may miss something (which I'm guessing is the case here)

Comment: but where did i messed up ? pls let me knw?

Comment: Are you sending an API token with the request? Since you're getting a unauthenticated I'm guessing you're not sending an API token with the request, which is required since you're using the `auth:api` middleware function. This requres an API token to be present in the request, in the form of an url parameter (`?api_token=`) or a header in the request.

Comment: and using middleware auth:api in protected function still gives the error unauthenticated ?

Comment: yes while sending the resend function it send the verification link but while getting it gives the error

Comment: but the same worked for web route ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201491/discussion-between-tim-and-aoudesh-jaiswal).

Comment: Hi,, have you sorted this out at last? What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {` code, since this requires the URL to have an API token (http://example.com/?api_token=[token]). If this token is not in the url, Laravel will throw a 401 - unauthenticated error.

You can also add an API token, for example by using the database API token (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication), but I wouldn't recommend this for email verification.

Since you're using the default Laravel email validation, you could also follow the steps in the Laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification) to enable email verification. By copying and pasting code from the internet, you're prone to errors.